# How can I get my publicist to stuff it?

Tags: dirt-3

My publicist chick and promoter dude are beginning to grate on me after only the first season.  Is there a way to get them to QFT so I can race in peace?  I can't skip their blabbering with [image: B] or anything.

Comment: Sounds like console from your reference to the "B" button.  If there's not an option in a menu to turn it off, you might be out of luck.

Comment: It is the PC version

Comment: You might have luck [editing the game files](http://www.moddb.com/games/dirt-3/tutorials/editing-dirt-3) and replacing the offending audio files with silence, although I don't own the game so I can't really say how easy that is to do.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](http://community.codemasters.com/forum/dirt-3-general-discussion-1339/466434-disable-annoying-voices.html), if you want to remove the voices, you need to find the file 'en_generic.nfs' in the audio speech folder and delete or rename it.

According to some people, this kills all voice audio in the game, including the co-driver voice, so you might not want to take this option if you want that voice to remain in game. Others have claimed that it doesn't remove the co-driver voice, though, so it is really a gamble.

Answer (score 1):

I just accidentally discovered, that if I switch the game (on pc) from full screen to windowed, it cancels whatever voice is talking.  THen I can switch back and continue playing.
Weird, but it works.

Comment: Might work, but it would probably interrupt the game more than the offending audio files in question.